# Can you convert this logic to other form ? IF-THEN

Tags: javascript

some logic = displayvalue ==='0' ? number : displayvalue + number

is there anyother way to right the If then , other that ? :

thanks

Comment: `let x = displayvalue + number; if (displayvalue === '0') { x = number; }`

Comment: That's missing the `else` @blex

Comment: No, there's no need for an `else`, @Dominik. It's the initial value (although I put it in the wrong order ;) Fixed

Comment: I see, you're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: For simplicity's sake I've just replaced my old answer

```js
let ondisplaynumber = 10

function expression(onDisplayValue) {
  return onDisplayValue === '0' ? ondisplaynumber : onDisplayValue + ondisplaynumber
}

console.log(expression('0'))
console.log(expression(20))
console.log(expression('a'))

function expressionRevised(onDisplayValue) {
  if (onDisplayValue === '0') {
    return ondisplaynumber
  } else {
    return onDisplayValue + ondisplaynumber
  }
}

console.log(expressionRevised('0'))
console.log(expressionRevised(20))
console.log(expressionRevised('a'))
```

Comment: calculatorDisplay.textContent = onDisplayValue === '0' ? ondisplaynumber : onDisplayValue + ondisplaynumber; my question is can it be written in other way insted of using the ? : for the argument even if it will look longer ? thanks

Comment: @Jackhammer see my edit. Is that what you mean?

Comment: omg this is it thanks a lot and have a beautiful week :) again big thanks